# is there any way to modify the strength of blur in AERO in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, aero

One other question of mine other than the one already in the title is, how exactly does the blur in windows work? How does it work so smoothly when being dragged compared to when it is artificially added to something like windows XP, or taking seconds for a single render in an image editing program like GIMP?

Comment: just to be clear, I don't want to disable blur, I just want to change how strong the effect is so I can have it slightly less but still noticeably blurred

Answer (score 1):

You can try out a Windows 7 [Aero Blur Tweaker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/Windows-7-Aero-Blur-Tweaker.shtml) tool which might help you enable/disable Aero blur effects  from Windows 7 UI.

Comment: I just want to change the intensity, but thanks for that. I already use that tweaker, along with having basically every patch that exists to allow custom-whatever